# Android Material Design Text Field Templates

Tags: android, layout, material-design

I am trying to design a layout that I found on Googles Material Design website, this one in particular.

[image]

Does anybody have any pointers on how to make this layout? Or know of any sample layout code? I can't seem to find any relating to this layout.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) mate

Comment: Thats a really nice library, but I don't see this layout being used anywhere in it.

Comment: There is a Floating Action Button included in that Library, designing this layout is pretty easy, what makes it charming are the animations.

Comment: @Skynet, this floting actrion button is already included as an scrollable example in android studio 2.3.3, however I still haven't seen any library to show text field template as you see in picture, although Google material design website have a lot of description about implementing it.